# "Search by tags" improvement

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

I think this simple tags search change would provide a better experience:

- Add tags to search by clicking on **[+]** button near the tag (on the right hand on questions page), instead of clicking on the tag itself.
- When a user clicks on a tag, system resets previous tags search and searches for newly chosen tag questions.

[image: screen shot with mockup UI]

Comment: This might be a nice to have, but I don't feel that this adds enough value to justify complicating the UI. If anything, holding a key down while clicking on a tag would be preferred (e.g. Shift+Click / Ctrl+Click, although both of those mean something in browsers, which [se] shouldn't mess with).

Comment: Do you mean "Related tags" instead of "Recent tags"? The latter is only there on the main screen to my knowledge, which, as I understand, isn't really what you're talking about.

Comment: As it stands this might be a bit confusing, "what does + mean, I already added this to my favourite tags", possible once you're already in search it might work

Comment: Can you elaborate on possible cases where you'd want to do this? To make sure we're on the same page and that you're not missing some functionality already available (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @Dukeling I just would like to have possibility to switch between tags faster. Intuitively I am trying to click on tags on the right hand of the page. But this click adds tags to search instead of switching between them.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree. Keep in mind that it is just personal opinion. Here are the reasons

1. I would never use it. I never search for tags by clicking on them, I just type them. I didn't even know about the clicking feature up until now.
2. The recent tags list is (at least for me, due to careers ad and favorite/ingored list) much below the search input. I would have to scroll the page quite a bit to see what tags have I enetered.
3. Each click causes page refresh. I hate that. When I type several tags at once and press enter, I get what I want. Your way I'd have to click (and scroll page) several times to get the same result. Not to mention the refreshes
4. The UI complexity would increase. There is enough stuff on the page right now.

Answer (score 0):

> When a user clicks on a tag, system resets previous tags search and searches for newly chosen tag questions.

I find the current behavior useful precisely because clicking on a tag adds it to the search. It's a handy way to restrict a search to a tag combination, as opposed to clicking on a tag below a question which switches the view to that tag.

So, no. If the behavior was what you're asking for, I'd be requesting to improve it to what it is now.